# Text created using for loops in kivymd looks cluttered

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivymd

I've been working on a small coding project, which is an App meant for Android. I created a screen called "Contraindicaciones" using a for loop in my python file, because of the amount of checkboxes that I had to make.

In this screen there are 10 checkboxes, each with its own label, on a 2 column GridLayout.

The problem is that the labels (both the title and the checkbox labels) look really cluttered when I adjust the size of the screen to something similar to a phone, which is really bad because the App will be used in Smartphones.

It would be of great help if you help me make the screen look more tidy, specially for a smartphone screen.

I've tried incrementing the spacing and decrementing the size of the labels, and also the font_size properties, but it didn't work, in fact incrementing the spacing made it look worse (the button in the top looks weird) and decrementing the size of the labels and the font_size didn't have an effect at all (which is weird)

```
class Contraindicaciones(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Scrollview
        self.scrollview_contraindicaciones = MDScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size = (Window.width, Window.height))

        # GridLayout
        layout_contraindicaciones = MDGridLayout(orientation = "lr-tb", spacing = "100dp", padding = "20dp", size_hint_x = 1, size_hint_y = None, cols = 2)
        layout_contraindicaciones.bind(minimum_height = layout_contraindicaciones.setter("height"))

        # Go Back Button:
        invisible_label1 = MDLabel(text = "")
        invisible_label1.size_hint_y = None
        invisible_label1.size_hint_x = 0.5
        invisible_label1.height = dp(50)

        back_button_layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation = "vertical")
        back_button = MDFillRoundFlatButton(text = "Anterior", font_name = "fonts/Lato-Bolditalic.ttf")
        back_button.haling = "left"
        back_button.size_hint_y = None
        back_button.size_hint_x = 0.8

        back_button.bind(on_release = self.back)

        back_button_layout.add_widget(back_button)
        layout_contraindicaciones.add_widget(back_button_layout)
        layout_contraindicaciones.add_widget(invisible_label1)

        #title
        title_label = MDLabel(text = "Contraindicaciones", halign="left")
        title_label.font_size = "15dp"
        title_label.size_hint_y = None
        title_label.size_hint_x = 1
        title_label.font_name = "fonts/Lato-Bolditalic.ttf"
        title_label.height = dp(50)

        # Invisible Label
        invisible_label2 = MDLabel(text = "")
        invisible_label2.size_hint_y = None
        invisible_label2.size_hint_x = 0.1
        invisible_label2.height = dp(50)

        # Title and Invisible Label to not mess the rest up
        layout_contraindicaciones.add_widget(title_label)
        layout_contraindicaciones.add_widget(invisible_label2)

        self.checkboxes = []

        contraindicaciones = ["Hemorragia intracraneal (HIC) previa", "Lesión vascular cerebral estructural conocida",
        "Neoplasia intracraneal maligna conocida ya sea primaria o metastásica", "Accidente cerebrovascular isquémico en un plazo de 3 meses",
        "Sospecha de disección aórtica", "Hemorragia activa o diátesis hemorrágica", "Traumatismo craneoencefálico cerrado importante o traumatismo facial en los últimos 3 meses",
        "Cirugía intracraneal o intramedular en un plazo de 3 meses", "Hipertensión no controlada grave", "En caso de estreptoquinasa, el tratamiento previo debe ser dentro de los 6 meses previos"]

        for i, contraindicacion in enumerate(contraindicaciones):
            size_checkbox = dp(32)
            size_labels = dp(12)
            checkbox = MDCheckbox(size_hint=(0.5, None), size=(size_checkbox, size_checkbox))
            label = MDLabel(text=contraindicacion, size_hint=(0.8, None), size=(size_labels, size_labels), font_size = "10dp", multiline = True)
            label.font_name = "fonts/Lato-Italic.ttf"
            layout_contraindicaciones.add_widget(label)
            layout_contraindicaciones.add_widget(checkbox)

            self.checkboxes.append(checkbox)

        # Button and invisible label
        invisible_label3 = MDLabel(text = "")
        invisible_label3.size_hint_y = None
        invisible_label3.size_hint_x = 0.5
        invisible_label3.height = dp(50)

        next_button = MDFillRoundFlatButton(text = "Continuar", font_name = "fonts/Lato-Bolditalic.ttf")
        next_button.haling = "right"
        next_button.size_hint_y = None
        next_button.size_hint_x = 0.5
        next_button.bind(on_release = self.forward)

        layout_contraindicaciones.add_widget(invisible_label3)
        layout_contraindicaciones.add_widget(next_button)

        #Se agrega Grid a Scroll
        self.scrollview_contraindicaciones.add_widget(layout_contraindicaciones)
        self.add_widget(self.scrollview_contraindicaciones)

    def back(self,*_):
        self.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        self.manager.current = "c_t"
    def forward(self,*_):
        if any(checkbox.active for checkbox in self.checkboxes):
            self.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            self.manager.current = "contra_n"
        else:
            self.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            self.manager.current = "t_y"
```